# Jquery Thumbnail images slideshow

Tags: jquery

I have created jquery image slider and it is working good. However i have problems with showing **thumbnail** images in my slider. This is my problem: under my slider are four thumbnail images and on every slide you can see witch image is "active" but my thumbnails (for now they are just letters) are working only until **last slide** and then it brakes:( 

Here is **[THE FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/MhFnR/)** with full code.

Here's my code for selecting thumbnails:

Can someone help me please?
Thank you!!!

```
  /*CODE WORKING UNTIL LAST SLIDE*/
 $('.control_active').removeClass('control_active').next('li').addClass('control_active');
      <!--------------------------------------------------------------------------------->
```

Comment: I think it stops working because there really isn't a next li. You want it to go back to the first li, but it wants to go on to another li that isn't there.

Comment: That is right but I dont know how to do it:(

Comment: Dejo try to integrate my answer. It will know what position it's in at all times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made really simple solution of my problem:)
Basically i am checking is there a class on the **last** li tag. If there is a class on **last** li tag add class to **first** li ,but only when first image starts again its animation... Here's the [**WORKING FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7HddN/). 

And here's the code:

```
   /*THIS CODE IS WORKING LIKE A CHARM YEEEY!!!*/ 
   <!----------------------------------------------->         
$('.control_active').removeClass('control_active').next('li').addClass('control_active');
if ($('.textcontrols ul li:last').hasClass('control_active')) {
  $('.textcontrols ul li:first').addClass('control_active');
 }
<!-------------------------------------------->
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty solution would be to set a flag and switch:

```
var slide_text = {
  red: $('.redcontrol'),
  blue: $('.bluecontrol'),
  green: $('.greencontrol'),
  yellow: $('.yellowcontrol')
}

var wash = function()
{
  for( var key in slide_text )
  {
    if( slide_text.hasOwnProperty(key) )
    {
      slide_text[key].removeClass('control_active');
    }
  }
}

var n = 0;
switch( n )
{
  //red
  case 0:
    wash();
    slide_text.red.addClass( 'control_active' );
    n++;
    break;

  //blue
  case 1:
    wash();
    slide_text.blue.addClass( 'control_active' );
    n++;
    break;

  //green
  case 2:
    wash();
    slide_text.green.addClass( 'control_active' );
    n++;
    break;

  //yellow
  case 3:
    wash();
    slide_text.yellow.addClass( 'control_active' );
    n = 0;
    break;
}
```